# (SQL Server 14) SQL Server WMI Provider is not available on <COMPUTER NAME>

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to enable the TCP/IP and Named Pipes Protocols using PowerShell, but I'm unable to due to the following error.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to connect to the Server Protocols.

[image]

Is there a way to make SQL Server WMI available through PowerShell?

Here is what the $machine variable looks like after this cmdlet:

```
$machine = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' -ArgumentList 'STORE000013'
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution to this? I have installed SqlServer module, and since then it's just ruined.

Comment: tbh, this was 5 years ago and with a different company. I forget what the solution to this was...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one... When running PowerShell (PowerShell.exe) instead of SQL Server PowerShell, first execute the following statements to manually load the required assemblies:

```
# Load the assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")
```

For more information, here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206997(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Just added that line, but I still got the same error as before.

Comment: Using administrator permissions?

Comment: Yeah. I also ran the commands through Command Prompt using sqlps.exe

Comment: I've tried the commands for sqlps.exe now too. Those work. And give a diferent output on "wmi" than you show. 
I also get Service, Client, Istances and Alias. So maybe you should try again those steps..